# What is the difference between “whack somebody around the shins” and “whack somebody on the shins”?

Tags: prepositions

> At Dudley’s fifth birthday party, Aunt Marge had whacked Harry around the shins with her walking stick to stop him from beating Dudley at musical statues. (Harry Potter 3, Scholastic Paperbacks p18)

Can you explain what the difference between *around* and *on* is?  I’d like to know if the *around* adds a subtle nuance to the sentence.

Comment: Wouldn't "about" fit here better than "around"?

Comment: You really should **start another question** with your edit; the title of this post is undescriptive as for your new edit, and "ninja edits" are discouraged here.

Comment: @Billare  Thank you for your advice. I didn’t know this kind of edit is called ‘ninja edit’, really. I’ll open another title immediately. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If J.K. Rowling had used *on* in place of *around*, I think that the reader's impression would be that Aunt Marge had only struck Harry once.  By using *around* the shins, she gives the impression that he was hit at multiple points on his shins, so that she can convey the idea that Aunt Marge is an especially cruel woman and her hitting Harry isn't just a sudden, uncharacteristic, outburst but rather part and parcel of her tormenting nature.

Comment: I agree.  Also, with "on" I get the impression of a clear shot directly to the shins, with "around" I get the impression that she was aiming for the shins, but some of the whacks may have hit the calf, thigh, or foot or missed altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It's just one of those slightly illogical BE sayings.
Like "clip around the ear" - it isn't meant to convey any particular detailed spatial reasoning.