# What do you call slapping someone at the back of their head

Tags: expressions

I know there is bitch-slap, that is when you you hit someone a male or a female with back of you hands (sometimes) when they act or do stupid. I want to know the word that is subtle in nature, that when we hit someone at the back of their head when they do stupid thing. Like an elder bro hit a younger one to correct him...

I know a word Gibbs-slap, but that is so american and I want a global term.

Thanks.

Comment: In the olden days when I was young, a common term for what you're describing was "cuff." To "buffet" meant to cuff repeatedly.

Comment: @Sven, _cuff_ is, to me at least, not specifically in the back of the head—in fact, the most immediate and natural collocation I can think of is cuffing someone on the _ear_ (or giving them a _cuff on the ear_).

Comment: I am "so american."  And I have never heard anything close to Gibbs-slap.

Comment: I agree, Janus, that _cuffing_ is specific about the portion of the anatomy that a person strikes with and not about the portion of the anatomy that receives the blow. Subjectively I always imagined that a cuff was less sharp than a slap, but I don't know whether other people generally made that distinction. A more target-specific term was "box [one's] ear"—but because of the image of boxers in a ring, I never associated that term with an open-handed swat or slap.

Comment: @Josh : NCIS dude.

Comment: I like cuff. You can cuff someone anywhere. Slap upside the head is colloquial and slang and is also Afro-American in origin. That's fine but one needs to know what the OP really wants. In the UK, they used to big on boxing kids on their ears.

Comment: As the Car Talk guys would tell you (when they were both alive), that's a "dope slap".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was referred to as **"slapping or smacking someone upside the head"** when I was growing up.  It's described [here](http://youtu.be/BdffmmnWZHs) in this comedy video by Chris Rock where a disgruntled doorman starts *smacking people upside the head* - always with an upward motion of the hand and usually on the back of the head.

This [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1995/02/12/magazine/on-language-upside-the-head.html) article talks about this expression as having started as one used by blacks and then adopted by all races in the southern part of the United States.  I went to high school in a racially mixed region of the US and heard this expression frequently.

Comment: Similar to that is the more BrE idiom of _smacking/slapping/clouting/etc. someone round the head_, which means the same thing to me, though slightly less specifically. In [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21851/whats-the-meaning-of-hit-him-round-the-head), Colin Fine states there is no particular part of the head indicated, but to me does indicate (absent any evidence to the contrary) that the smack in question was in the back of the head.

Comment: +1 - I didn't realize this was an AAVE phrase rather than a general one, but then AAVE was the predominant dialect at my grade school, so perhaps I wouldn't notice.

Comment: According to Kipfer & Chapman, _Dictionary of American Slang_, Fourth Edition (2007), "go (or hit) upside one's face (or head)" means "1 To beat or pummel, esp around the head 2 To defeat utterly; trounce; CLOBBER (1960s+ Black)." That doesn't sound much like "slap on the back of one's head" to me, but I don't have a better phrase to offer in its stead.

Comment: All this is true but it is a very marked expression.

Answer (score 3):

[*Dope slap*](https://www.google.com/search?q=dope+slap) is the most common expression I know for striking someone in the back of the head with an open palm. The *b*-expression, which I will not repeat, usually refers to a different kind of strike, typically a backhand across the face (or am I thinking of the pimp slap?).

Comment: Good one.... So is this common enough for people to understand what I am trying to convey?

Comment: I'm not British, but [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q="dope+slap"+site:uk) comes up with examples of people using the term there.

Comment: As an American, I've never heard the term.  But if you said "I dope slapped my kid brother" I'd at least still get the general meaning.

Comment: I've heard "dope slap" all my life. I understand it to be a light smack in the back or side of the head, not intended to be painful, more of a form of physical exclamation point on the end of "What were you thinking?"

Comment: There is it: smacked him on the back of the head. Smacked is good. Dope slap is too regional.

Comment: @Lambie - If you ever listened to NPR, [dope slap](http://www.cartalk.com/content/volvo-dope-slap-1) was a favorite term of the Car Talk guys.  That alone would make it known across the country.

Comment: Perhaps it was. I listened to it for years. I just have never heard it. Can't hear/know everything, right? But my ears are always open, so I assume it is not all that common. I come from their neck of the woods by the way....

Answer (score 1):

seftie or sefty Australian slang for a open handed slap up the back of the head

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As StackExchange seeks to develop a library of *definitive* answers, your answer could be improved if you could provide examples, as from publications or other media, or a definition from a dictionary or other reference. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

**Wallop** can be used to describe a defeat or a hit, but is also used to describe a hit to the back of the head.